# MonoDevelop C# (Gtk#), Syntax-Highlighting for Gtk.TextView

Tags: c#, events, mono, gtk, syntax-highlighting

I am developing sth like an editor with **C# (Gtk)** with **MonoDevelop**.

I wanna include some tool like syntax highlightening.
I've read sth about the *GtkSourceView*, but it seems, that it isn't available in Mono.
I thought I could add sth like a **TextChange** Event to my *Gtk.TextView* widget, but it's also not possible.
In another post someone said, that it's possible to realize syntax highlighting by using the **keyPress** event.
But the keyPress event won't work.

Note 1: Gtk.TextEditor doesn't work. Mono won't compile the project while trying to use Gtk.TextEditor

So what do I have to do, to realize a syntax highlighting for my *Gtk.TextView*?

Comment: You probably want to use gtksourceview instead, since it already exists. But if that's not an option, and if your keypress event won't work, we'll have to see your source. And whatever this Gtk.TextEditor thing is, what errors do you get?

Comment: "It seems that Mono.TextEditor is a reimplementation of GtkTextView and
GtkSourceView"
~ Mono mailing list

`protected void on_Key (object o, KeyPressEventArgs args)
 {
  tvEdit.Buffer.Text = tvRaw.Buffer.Text;
 }`
But nothing happens.
GtkSourceView isn't available.
I get no error with Gtk.TextEditor when I try to compile.
It only won't compile.
There's no mistake